# Connect Win7 notebook display to iMac

Tags: imac, display, windows, thunderbolt, displayport

I'm looking for a solution to extend my Windows 7 based notebook display to my iMac. The notebook provides the following connectors:

1x VGA

1x Displayport

1x Expresscard/34

I have already tried to connect both computers via Displayport to Thunderbolt adapter but tests showed up that my iMac only supports Thunderbolt to Thunderbolt connections. I have also tried to connect them accross network based software solutions but the notebook firewall which is not under my control prevented this. Any further ideas?

Comment: It would help if you listed the model of the iMac

Comment: Model 21,5" iMac i7 bought in January 2012

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about connecting non-Apple hardware to Apple hardware.

Comment: @Rob That doesn't make this question off-topic—it involves Apple hardware therefore is within the scope.

Comment: This involves target display mode, so it's clearly on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your iMac can only support TDM using thunderbolt connections, and as such can not be connected to your laptop.
You can learn more about TDM in [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US#12)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somehow I hoped that some kind of real Displayport to Thunderbolt gateway adapter exists that allow me to overcome that limitation.

Comment: that kind of adapter does not exist, the thunderbolt signal needs to come from your pc and no adapter can just "make up" that signal.

Comment: Do you know if a corresponding USB 3.0 or Expresscard/34 to Thunderbolt converter exists?

Comment: there are some adapters out there but they all rely on the host computer to have the thunderbolt port and in your case it is the other way around.

Comment: Somehow I feared that answer. In that case I will try to convince the companys firewall department to open the required network flows to implement a software based solution. Anyway thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Yw, too bad there isn't a easier solution, consider accepting the answer if it solved your question.